# Kähler potential for ALEs from resolving $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$:

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, hyperkaehler

I am reading the famous paper of Kronheimer “The construction of ALE spaces as hyperkähler quotients”

I want to calculate explicitly the metric on the ALE spaces, obtained by a family of resolution of $\mathbb{C}^2/\mathbb{Z}_2$.

One answer in [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/331418/kronheimers-results-on-ale-spaces-as-hyperkahler-quotients/331436#331436?newreg=ceaade305b044536a8b7b3bd5d42b36c) stated the results, but I cannot obtain them. Could someone show me the way or some references?
Thank you very much!